# Single instance of Route in backstack

Tags: flutter

In android there was a simple way of doing this in the manifest: `android:launchMode="singleTask"`

This removed the previous instance of the activity in the backstack wherever it was. Any way of achieving that flutter?

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you don't want add that bit of code to the app's android manifest in Flutter?

Comment: All the routes in flutter operate under a single Android Activity. Flutter has a different backstack and simply adding that code won't work.